# VBA: Copy cells from one work book to another_ not working for big data

Tags: vba, excel

I have developed the following code to export data from all csv files in a directory and put them in one new workbook. It works for smaller number of data but when we have thousands of rows it won't work.

```
Sub Button4_Click()
Dim CSVPath
Dim thisWb As Workbook
Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim CSVUsed As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWb.Path & "\new_workbook.xls"
'ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CSVPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CSV"
If Not FS.FolderExists(CSVPath) Then
    MsgBox "CSV folder does not exist."
    Exit Sub
End If
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each file In FS.GetFolder(CSVPath).Files
    If Right(file.Name, 3) = "csv" Then
        Set wkb = Application.Workbooks.Open(file.Path)
        Set CSVUsed = wkb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
        For i = 1 To CSVUsed.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To CSVUsed.Columns.Count
        thisWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, i).Value = CSVUsed.Cells(j, i).Value
        Next
        Next
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

As The number of columns are not fixed, I didn't use range.
Can some one help?

Comment: VBA is not VB.NET, please don't misuse tags

Comment: vba: its not VB.NET, just like it says on the tags

Comment: Dim i As long, j as long

Comment: if you define it as integer, the max value will be 32,768 and can cause an issue with your count if you dataset is larger than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Cells` arguments are `Row`, `Column`.  **Not** `Column`, `Row`.  In reading these lines

```
    For i = 1 To CSVUsed.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To CSVUsed.Columns.Count
    thisWb.Sheets(1).Cells(j, i).Value = CSVUsed.Cells(j, i).Value
```

**I believe you've swapped the rows and columns.**  I'm surprised it works fine in small cases, unless the row and column count happen to be close enough for your proofing.  Also, `i` and `j` may need to be `long` instead of `int`

> If you define it as integer, the max value will be 32,768 and can
>   cause an issue with your count if you dataset is larger than that. -VBA Pete

It wouldn't matter for columns, as the max is 16,384, but you could have 1,048,576 rows.